# Float middle inhering remaining area

Tags: html, css

Here's the code snippet I am having a problem with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .container {
            background: gray;
        }
        .container .left {
            float: left;
            background: red;
        }
        .container .right {
            float: right;
            background: blue;
        }
        .container .middle {
            float: middle;
            background: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <span class="left">Left</span>
        <span class="middle">Middle</span>
        <span class="right">Right</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am having problem making `<span class='middle'>` cover the remaining grey area from parent element `div`. How could I make it, `<span class='middle'>`, cover all of the remaining grey area?

Thanks.

Comment: float: middle; is not a thing, you should go read up on some float rules and actual properties of it. This may be of help: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"float:middle" does not exist.

To achieve you layout, you can add `display:block;` to the middle `<span>` so it uses the whole grey area :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/eXZFy/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="left">Left</span>
    <span class="right">Right</span>
    <span class="middle">Middle</span>
</div>
```

notice you need to change the order of elements in the HTML markup : right div must go before "middle" div

*CSS :*

```
    .container {
        background: gray;
    }
    .container .left {
        float: left;
        background: red;
    }
    .container .right {
        float: right;
        background: blue;
    }
    .container .middle {
        display:block;
        background: green;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But there's a problem with `Right`, it's displayed in the next line positioned on the right.

Comment: @Dr.Java As I posted, you need to change the order of the HTML markup : "right div must go before "middle" div"